# FSM in VHDL is Moore or Mealy?

Tags: vhdl, automata

I am coding a FSM in VHDL. In particular it is a synchronized sequence detector that has in input a number on 8 bit and a "first", that has to be '1' only during the first number of the sequence. The output is composed by an unlock and warning: unlock = '1' if the sequence (36, ...) was right, or warning = '1' if the sequence was wrong or first = '1' not during the first number of the sequence.

In VHDL I use two processes, one synchronized and one not. The simplified version of the second is:

```
state_register_p : process(clk)
    begin 
        if (clk'EVENT and clk = '1') then
            if(rst = '0') then
                current_state <= S0;

                errors_num <= "00";
                five_cycles <= "000";
                first_error <= '1';
            else
                current_state <= next_state;

                if correct = '0' then
                    errors_num <= errors_num + "01";
                else
                    errors_num <= "00";
                end if;

            end if;

        end if;

end process state_register_p;

combinatorial_logic_p : process(current_state, num_in, first)

    begin       
        unlock <= '0';
        warning <= '0';

        case (current_state) is             
            when S0 =>
                if (to_integer(unsigned(num_in)) = 36) and (first = '1') then
                    next_state <= S1;
                else
                    next_state <= S0;
           when S1 =>
                correct <= '0';
                if (to_integer(unsigned(num_in)) = 19) and (first = '0') and errors_num /= "11" then
                    next_state <= S2;
                elsif first = '1' or errors_num = "11" then
                    next_state <= S6;
                else
                    next_state <= S0;
                end if;

            when S2 =>
                correct <= '0';
                if (to_integer(unsigned(num_in)) = 56)  and (first = '0') then
                    next_state <= S3;
                elsif first = '1' then
                    next_state <= S6;
                else
                    next_state <= S0;
                end if;

            when S3 =>
                correct <= '0';
                if (to_integer(unsigned(num_in)) = 101) and (first = '0') then
                    next_state <= S4;
                elsif first = '1' then
                    next_state <= S6;
                else
                    next_state <= S0;
                end if;

            when S4 =>
                correct <= '0';
                if (to_integer(unsigned(num_in)) = 73) and (first = '0') and (to_integer(unsigned(five_cycles)) = 5) then
                    next_state <= S5;
                    correct <= '1';
                elsif first = '1' then
                    next_state <= S6;
                else
                    next_state <= S0;
                end if;

            when S5 =>
                correct <= '1';
                if to_integer(unsigned(num_in)) = 36 and (first = '1') then
                    next_state <= S1;
                else
                    next_state <= S0;
                end if;

                unlock <= '1';

            when S6 =>
                correct <= '0';
                next_state <= S6; -- default, hold in current state
                warning <= '1';

        end case;               
end process combinatorial_logic_p;
```

By reading online I know that in a Moore machine the next state depends on the current state only so the outputs only change on clock edges, while in Mealy it depends also on the input so its outputs may change when an input changes (i.e., not necessarily on a clock edge). .

In my sensitivity list I use current_state and 2 inputs (num_in and first), so is it possible to say that I am describing a Mealy machine or is it still a Moore machine because I am waiting the next rising edge to update the output?

I still think it is Moore, but I am not sure. Thanks

Comment: It is a Mealy state machine, if output `unlock` or `warning` depends on any of the inputs `num_in` or `first`, and a Moore state machine of the outputs only depend on `current_state`.  This [figure](https://allthingsvlsi.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/fsms.jpg) has a nice presentation.  However, your code does not show how the outputs are driven, assuming they are not trivial 0, so please update the code... but you can probably determine the answer yourself now ;-)

Comment: Thanks @MortenZilmer. My doubts were related to the fact that many books say that in a Mealy machine the output may change not on the rising edge, but it is not my case since the output update is done by the process not shown here, the synchronized one. But in your figure says the output is asynchronous... EDIT: added the rest of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a Moore state machine, since the outputs `unlock` and `warning` depend only on `current_state` in the `combinatorial_logic_p` process.

Note that the signals `errors_num` and `five_cycles` are used in the `combinatorial_logic_p` process, but forgotten in the sensitivity list.  So add them, or change to `(all)` if using VHDL-2008.

Comment: You are right, I have put the old version of my code, in fact Vivado rised an error because of their misses in the sensitivity list. So it is Moore, and it makes sense since the output changes only at the rising edge of the clock, even if my input are given through a synchronized testbench. So the main idea is that the combinatorial process sets the state, but it is still Moore because it becomes effective only when the sync process assign it to the current_state. Thanks, you solved my doubts.

Comment: You may consider driving the output in a separate process, or a continuous assignment, to make it obvious that they do not depend on the inputs, if that property is crucial to the design.

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer, if it is the best solution, as described here [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I did a solution with three processes, I am comparing them to see what is better and easier to debug.